# how to display tweet after it was sent?

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter

I'm working on a twitter app and i want to immediately display tweet after sending. I tried to use reloadData, but it didn't work. Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Here's my code:

```
- (IBAction)postNewTweet:(id)sender {
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
{
    SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    [tweetSheet setInitialText:@""];

    [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tweetTableView reloadData];
    });

}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Sorry"
                              message:@"You can't send a tweet right now, make sure your device has an internet connection and you have at least one Twitter account setup"
                              delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blaze, you are reloading the table view right after presenting the compose sheet, so it reload the table right there - and you are passing the completion block as nil, so nothing will happen when user finishes tweeting.

Also, you need to be sure that you are reloading not only the table, but the array or any other object that is the source of tweetTableView.

For example:

When calling the tweet compose sheet:

```
[self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self reloadTweets];
    });
}];
```

And then, you reload the tweets source and only then the table

```
-(void)reloadTweets
{
    tweetsArray = .... //load the tweets from the internet, and only then reload the table

    [self.tweetTableView reloadData];
}
```